# Make onkeydown events occur only once for specific keys

Tags: javascript, html, 2d-games

I am creating a simple game with functions to move a player forward,turn left,turn right, or turn around. I want the key presses to fire the specific corresponding function only once.  I found this helpful code that fires the event only once, but I cannot seem to figure out how to specify certain key presses within it.

```
    var shouldHandleKeyDown = true;
    document.onkeydown = function(){
      if (!shouldHandleKeyDown) return;
      shouldHandleKeyDown = false;
      // HANDLE KEY DOWN HERE
    }
    document.onkeyup = function(){
      shouldHandleKeyDown = true;
    }
})();
```

What I am trying to make happen is:

User presses up?
Move forward function occurs ONCE (even if the up key is held)

User presses left? Turn left function occurs once etc....

Thank you all for any help with this.

EDIT FOR CLARIFICATION:

I am trying to build a first-person dungeon crawler in the style of old titles like Wizardry for the NES.  Basically I want each press of the forward button to move the player forward one frame. If they press left then the player turns left one frame, etc.  If you are familiar with the games you will get what I mean.

Comment: Dont forget to accept one answer which helps you (by click on big gray check button on its left side) you can also add +10 points to author by click on upper triangle (to many answers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would ignore onkeydown events and just use onkeyup.  That way the event is only fired once the user lifts their finger, ensuring just one movement per key press.

To determine which key was pressed inside your event handler, pass the event to your function.  [Here](https://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes) is a link to the values of the keys, so you could do something like:

```
document.onkeyup = function(event) {
    var keycode = event.keyCode;

    if (keycode === 38) {
        moveUp();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey this absolutely worked, and now that I am implementing it just seems so obvious.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is no single good way to tackle this problem, it mostly depends on what you'll do with these key inputs.

For instance, if it is to control an always updating animation, then simple semaphores in a dictionary with `{left: bool, right: bool, up: bool, down: bool}` sets to `true` in *keydown* and to `false` in *keyup*, and that gets checked at every frame is enough.

```js
const directions = {
  up: false,
  right: false,
  down: false,
  left: false
};
onkeydown = e => {
  const key = e.key.replace('Arrow', '').toLowerCase();
  if(key in directions) {
    e.preventDefault();
    directions[key] = true;
  }
};
onkeyup = e => {
  const key = e.key.replace('Arrow', '').toLowerCase();
  if(key in directions) {
    e.preventDefault();
    directions[key] = false;
  }
};
const w = canvas.width = innerWidth;
const h = canvas.height = innerHeight;
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
const character = {
  x: w/2,
  y: h/2,
  update: function() {
    const speed = 2;
    // this is where we will check our keyboard's status
    // we do it every frame
    let dir_x = 0,
      dir_y = 0;
    dir_x += directions.left ? -1 : 0;
    dir_x += directions.right ? 1 : 0;
    dir_y += directions.up ? -1 : 0;
    dir_y += directions.down ? 1 : 0;
    this.x += dir_x * speed;
    this.y += dir_y * speed;
  },
  draw: function() {
    ctx.fillRect(this.x - 20, this.y-20, 40, 40);
  }
};

function anim() {
  character.update();
  ctx.clearRect(0,0,w, h);
  character.draw();
  requestAnimationFrame(anim);
}
anim();
```

```css
:root,body{margin:0px}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

However if you are not keeping a continuous animation loop and really need this event to fire at first action, then in the keydown handler you may need to add a logic

```
...
if(key in directions) {
  e.preventDefault();
  const changed = directions[key] !== true;
  directions[key] = true;
  if(changed) {
    triggerChange(key);
  }
}
```

Where `triggerChange(key)` would be a function ready to trigger your solo action.

```js
const directions = {
  up: false,
  right: false,
  down: false,
  left: false
};

function triggerChange(dir) {
  character.update();
}

onkeydown = e => {
  const key = e.key.replace('Arrow', '').toLowerCase();
  if (key in directions) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const changed = directions[key] !== true;
    directions[key] = true;
    if (changed) {
      triggerChange(key);
    }
  }
};
onkeyup = e => {
  const key = e.key.replace('Arrow', '').toLowerCase();
  if (key in directions) {
    e.preventDefault();
    directions[key] = false;
  }
};

const w = canvas.width = innerWidth;
const h = canvas.height = innerHeight;
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
const character = {
  x: w / 2,
  y: h / 2,
  update: function() {
    const speed = 5;
    // this is where we will check our keyboard's status
    // we do it every frame
    let dir_x = 0,
      dir_y = 0;
    dir_x += directions.left ? -1 : 0;
    dir_x += directions.right ? 1 : 0;
    dir_y += directions.up ? -1 : 0;
    dir_y += directions.down ? 1 : 0;
    this.x += dir_x * speed;
    this.y += dir_y * speed;
  },
  draw: function() {
    ctx.fillRect(this.x - 20, this.y - 20, 40, 40);
  }
};

function anim() {
  // it is now keydown that is responsible for character.update()
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, w, h);
  character.draw();
  requestAnimationFrame(anim);
}
anim();
```

```css
:root,body{margin:0}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Answer (score -1):

Change `function()` to `function(e)` and pressed key is in `e.key`

(after run snippet click on white rectangle below run button and press keys)

```js
var shouldHandleKeyDown = true;
document.onkeydown = function(e) {
  if (!shouldHandleKeyDown) return;
  shouldHandleKeyDown = false;
  console.log(e.key);
      // HANDLE KEY DOWN HERE
}

document.onkeyup = function(){
  shouldHandleKeyDown = true;
}
```